# How to show Codeigniter page in Facebook tab (iframe)

Tags: facebook, codeigniter

I've created a Facebook page for my business and have created a 'Jobs' tab which will pull in content from my HTTPS Codeigniter powered website.

What Facebook does is request the page via an HTTP POST request, which is resulting in a **403 Forbidden** error with the message "An Error Was Encountered - The action you have requested is not allowed.".

Additional info: I'm running Codeigniter 3 and Nginx.

Anyone know how I can get the page showing within Facebook?

Comment: Check if you correctly configured it to accept POST requests on that route.

Answer (score 2):

1)You should check if the requested url is correct. I sometimes use Postman extension for Chrome to do that.

2) If you call from Facebook with ajax, you should know that ajax does not allow cross-domain calling by default. The easy solution would be to use GET method to send the data, and no ajax.(There are some ticks to make cross domain calls with ajax too, but I'll get into detail only if necessary)

Comment: Thanks @Vali S. 1) url is definitely correct and 2) no idea re ajax - just added our page url into the 'Secure page tab url' of the corresponding FB app that you have to create.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!!! Simply by disabling CSRF protection for the page in question. Simple as that.

Comment: Cool! How did you know? :))

Comment: Well, you nailed it. Happy coding!